# Difference between findIndex() and some() in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, find

Is the difference just that while `some()` returns true if there's at least element that passes the test in the callback function, `findIndex()` returns index of the first element that succeeds the test?

Or is one more optimal or is there more to it than I understand, because, if that's the only difference then I could simply get the index from `findIndex()` and check if it's -1 or not.

```
let foo = [
    {
'animal':'dog'
},    
 {
'animal':'cat'
},    
 {
'animal':'cow'
},    
]

foo.find( obj => obj.animal === 'cat' ) 
{animal: "cat"}
foo.some( obj => obj.animal === 'cat' ) 
true
```

Comment: In fact, you are right, but sometimes it's just handy to get `true` or `false` depending on whether an element exists with that test or not. (Note: If you care about the index, go and use `findIndex`)

Comment: do you care about the index? Than use find. If you do not care about the index, use some. Or you can use `includes` which is like `some`

Comment: Are you asking about `find` or `findIndex`?

Comment: "*if that's the only difference then I could simply get the index from findIndex() and check if it's -1 or not.*" - well, you could also just use `reduce` which is even more fundamental… Using `some` is more optimal because it makes code easier to read and maintain when  you write what you *mean*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`findIndex`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.findindex) and [`some`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.some) are indeed very similar and you can easily use `findIndex` instead of `some`. Also, [`find`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-array.prototype.find) has a similar specification. But you cannot easily use it to replace `some` as the return value of `find` is the found element or `undefined` which you cannot tell apart from an actual element.

There is, however, a small difference between `findIndex`/`find` and `some`. See the specification of `some`:

> `callbackfn` is called only for elements of the array which actually exist; it is not called for missing elements of the array.

See this example:

```
new Array(1).findIndex(() => console.log('called')); // prints 'called' once
new Array(1).some(() => console.log('called')); // does not print anything
```

That should not actually be relevant in most applications, though.

The reason why those functions exist and you should use them how they were specified is readability. You should always strive to write readable/maintanable code. Of course you can write `[].findIndex(...) !== -1` instead of `[].some(...)` but the latter is clearly more readable as it has better semantics of what it does.